# getting yesterday stopped working after few days jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting yesterday with a function in `jquery` which was working fine few days back but all of sudden its not giving me yesterday date.

```
getYesterdaysDate = ->
  date = new Date
  date.setDate date.getDate() - 1
  date.getFullYear() + '/' + date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate()
```

that was working fine but now its giving me totally different date, why is it so? any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: 2016/11/1 this date..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some brackets -

```
date = new Date
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
date.getFullYear() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate();
```

Comment: any integer appearing after a string will be added as a string by '+' operator. For Eg. '/'+1+1 => /11